# How to make if else statement in magento 1 customize search bar

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a problem on this code :

```
if(isset($_POST['btn-save'])){
    $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
    $readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
    $table = $resource->getTableName('catalog/product');
    $search = $_POST['gsearch'];
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM ' . $table . 'WHERE name LIKE' .$search.'';
    $results = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);
     foreach($results as $res){
        echo $res ['name'];
     }
}
```

Comment: First of all, the 'catalog_prdouct_entity' table has no field 'name'. So you have to join the attribute value table before searching by the field.

Answer (score 0):

Magento have follow, **eav structure for  product structure**, and name is a varchar attribute.So it value have save at `catalog_product_entity_varchar` table.

### In standard code is

```
if ($this->getRequest()->isPost() && $this->getRequest()->getPost('btn-save')) {

    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('name');
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('name',array('like'=> '% '.$this->getRequest()->getPost('gsearch').' %'));
    $names = $collection->getColumnValues('name');


}
```